# Unexpected branch count in coverage data

Tags: c++, code-coverage, gcov

I generate coverage data and use an online service for visualization and CI. However I have strange "partials" (if-branches that are not fully covered). Looking at the gcov data it seems like an excessive amount of branches is detected.

An example:

```
function _ZNK5World8AdjustBQE5PointItEh15BuildingQuality called 415 returned 100% blocks executed 76%
      415:  377:BuildingQuality World::AdjustBQ(const MapPoint pt, unsigned char player, BuildingQuality nodeBQ) const
        -:  378:{
      415:  379:    if(nodeBQ == BQ_NOTHING || GetNode(pt).owner != player + 1 || !IsPlayerTerritory(pt))
branch  0 taken 95% (fallthrough)
branch  1 taken 5%
call    2 returned 100%
call    3 returned 100%
branch  4 taken 100% (fallthrough)
branch  5 taken 0% (throw)
branch  6 taken 85% (fallthrough)
branch  7 taken 15%
call    8 returned 100%
call    9 returned 100%
branch 10 taken 100% (fallthrough)
branch 11 taken 0% (throw)
branch 12 taken 17% (fallthrough)
branch 13 taken 83%
branch 14 taken 80% (fallthrough)
branch 15 taken 20%
branch 16 taken 95% (fallthrough)
branch 17 taken 5%
branch 18 taken 33% (fallthrough)
branch 19 taken 67%
branch 20 never executed
branch 21 never executed
branch 22 never executed
branch 23 never executed
call   24 never executed
```

It seems like the functions still get inlined and counted, although I'm already compiling with `-g -O0 --coverage -fno-default-inline -fno-inline`. What can I do, so I only get the "meaningfull" data and inline-functions are attributed correctly at their definition?

I'm using g++-4.8 and gcov-4.8

Edit: If I split the if into its calls I get this:

```
      415:  379:    unsigned char owner = GetNode(pt).owner;
call    0 returned 100%
call    1 returned 100%
branch  2 taken 100% (fallthrough)
branch  3 taken 0% (throw)
call    4 never executed
      415:  380:    bool isPlayerTer = IsPlayerTerritory(pt);
call    0 returned 100%
call    1 returned 100%
branch  2 taken 100% (fallthrough)
branch  3 taken 0% (throw)
call    4 never executed
      415:  381:    if(nodeBQ == BQ_NOTHING || owner != player + 1 || !isPlayerTer)
branch  0 taken 95% (fallthrough)
branch  1 taken 5%
branch  2 taken 85% (fallthrough)
branch  3 taken 15%
branch  4 taken 17% (fallthrough)
branch  5 taken 83%
```

So the problem is really the calls. What can I do so those calls (and their branches(???)) don't get added to the coverage data?

Just found an artificial branch in the asm code that just checks a register and does a nop (besides a gcov counter increment) WTF?

```
   0x0000000000d967de <World::AdjustBQ(Point<unsigned short>, unsigned char, BuildingQuality) const+340>:   test   %bl,%bl
   0x0000000000d967e0 <World::AdjustBQ(Point<unsigned short>, unsigned char, BuildingQuality) const+342>:   je     0xd967f5 <World::AdjustBQ(Point<unsigned short>, unsigned char, BuildingQuality) const+363>
   0x0000000000d967e2 <World::AdjustBQ(Point<unsigned short>, unsigned char, BuildingQuality) const+344>:   nop
   0x0000000000d967e3 <World::AdjustBQ(Point<unsigned short>, unsigned char, BuildingQuality) const+345>:   mov    0x1206c9e(%rip),%rax        # 0x1f9d488 <__gcov0._ZNK5World8AdjustBQE5PointItEh15BuildingQuality+72>
   0x0000000000d967ea <World::AdjustBQ(Point<unsigned short>, unsigned char, BuildingQuality) const+352>:   add    $0x1,%rax
   0x0000000000d967ee <World::AdjustBQ(Point<unsigned short>, unsigned char, BuildingQuality) const+356>:   mov    %rax,0x1206c93(%rip)        # 0x1f9d488 <__gcov0._ZNK5World8AdjustBQE5PointItEh15BuildingQuality+72>
   0x0000000000d967f5 <World::AdjustBQ(Point<unsigned short>, unsigned char, BuildingQuality) const+363>:   test   %dl,%dl
```

I switched to clang++ and `llvm-cov gcov` and got the correct results for this case (only 6 branches). However I also got some false positives at other places. One of the most disturbing ones seems to be a "function __cxx_global_array_dtor call" in the middle of a function on a line where similar lines (only integer parameters are changed) do not have this. So my current solution is to use gcov-4.8 without branch data as it is completely unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that there are additional branches at points, where exceptions could possibly occure, e.g. at function call points.

For example we observed a branch with gcov in our (not noexcept) empty virtual destructor, which we cannot Cover by our tests.

Comment: This one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199360/what-is-the-branch-in-the-destructor-reported-by-gcov?rq=1 ? However this is the call site. There should not be any branches at the call site, should there?

Comment: Interesting comment. It seems that the branch we observed is from the dynamic/nondynamic distintiction, not from an exception branch. We could then cover this by tests. I will try it on Monday.