# lcov: branches coverage of destructor missing

Tags: c++, code-coverage, lcov

My working environment

- cygwin
- lcov 1.13
- GCC 5.4.0

Problem is coverage report in html told that missing branch in destructor but the destructor is empty. I don't know why.
Anyone can help me ?
I also try with GCC 4.8.0 but same result
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found  [this on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199360/what-is-the-branch-in-the-destructor-reported-by-gcov).
The short answer is that there are different types of destructors, depending on whether you delete a dynamically allocated object, or is a statically allocated object destructed.

So to get rid of this missing branch coverage, you have to create an object with

```
TestClass* a = new TestClass();
```

and

```
TestClass b;
```

and then make sure, they are both destroyed, the former, of course, with

```
delete a;
```

Then both types of destructor should be called.

Comment: I created the object as "TestClass b;"
The destructor already called but it missing branches

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to add `// GCOVR_EXCL_LINE` as a comment to your line that you know is not executing both branches. I think this is a good idea for this case, as from my understanding there isn't another way to force GCOV to take both dynamic and non-dynamic branches of the destructor.

For example:

```
TestClass *a = new TestClass;
delete a; // GCOVR_EXCL_LINE
```

will exclude the `delete a;` line from the coverage report.

See the following for more details:
https://gcovr.com/en/master/guide.html#exclusion-markers