# vtable layout for avr-g++

Tags: c++, gcc, avr, vtable, avr-gcc

I don't fully understand the vtable-layout avr-g++ uses on the AVR platform.

I found that for a class hierarchy without a virtual dtor the vtable of a type looks like

```
(always) 0
(always) 0
ptrToFunc1
ptrToFunc2
...
```

In the case of a virtual dtor it looks like

```
(always) 0
(always) 0
dtor
dtor
ptrToFunc1
ptrToFunc2
...
```

The questions are:

1) what are the first two entries for?
2) why are there two entries for dtors?

and

3) can one save the first two entries (they seem to be 0 in every case)?

Comment: ad destructors. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44558119/why-do-i-have-two-destructor-implementations-in-my-assembly-output

Comment: Maybe also important: avr-gcc copies vtables to ram! This waste a lot of memory and makes it often impossible to use c++ on small devices. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43745. This will never be fixed, the entry is from 2010. At this point I switched to arm devices...

Comment: Yes, thats mostly due to the Harvard-architekture ... So theres is per class overhead in RAM and a per object overhead for the vptr.